# condicionar la ejecucion de un metodo segun un array

Tags: php

estoy ejecutando un metodo llamado subirResolucion que recibe un array llamado $pendiente_firma['id_documento_original'] o en su defecto recibe $pendiente_firma['id_documento_transparencia'], actualmente estas variables traen 2 datos cada una, entonces el metodo deberia ejecutarse 4 veces, 2 por cada $pendiente_firma['']. el caso es que se esta ejecutando el doble un total de 8 llamadas, me podrían ayudar que podría hacer que se este ejecutando de esa forma

```
  foreach ($data as $llave => $valor) {
                           \Core\SysLogger::info(__CLASS__, basename(__FILE__).' -> 
  '.__FUNCTION__.'('.__LINE__.') Test --->'.var_export($valor, true));
                            $es_subsidio = false;
                            $data[$llave]['id_documento'] = 'NULL';
                            $data[$llave]['id_estado_solicitud'] = 1;
                            $data[$llave]['id_usuario'] = $user->getId();
                            $data[$llave]['numero_resolucion'] = $pendientes_firma[$key] 
   ['folio'];
                            $data[$llave]['id_resolucion'] = $pendientes_firma[$key] 
    ['id_resolucion'];
                            $data[$llave]['id_documento_original'] = 
    $pendientes_firma[$key]['id_documento_original'];
                            $data[$llave]['id_documento_transparencia'] = 
    $pendientes_firma[$key]['id_documento_transparencia'];
                            if (trim($data[$llave]['numero_solicitud_subsidio'])!='') {
                                $data[$llave]['id_solicitud'] = $data[$llave] 
    ['numero_solicitud_subsidio'];
                                $es_subsidio = true;
                            }

                              \Core\SysLogger::info(__CLASS__, basename(__FILE__).' -> 
    '.__FUNCTION__.'('.__LINE__.') El pendiente de firma esta en estado de votacion 
    '.$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_voto']);

                            if ($es_subsidio && $pendientes_firma[$key]['id_voto'] == 2) 
     {
                                $respuesta = $this->modelo- 
     >enviarUnaResolucionTesoreria($data[$llave]);

                                if ($respuesta[0]['id_solicitud_generada']==0) {
                                    $response['solicitudes'][] = $data[$llave] 
     ['id_solicitud'];
                                    $idSolicitud = $data[$llave]['id_solicitud'];
                                } else {
                                    $response['solicitudes'][] = $respuesta[0] 
     ['id_solicitud_generada'];
                                    $idSolicitud = $respuesta[0] 
     ['id_solicitud_generada'];
                                }

                                $plan_pago = array();
                                $plan_pago['nro_cuota'] = 1;
                                $plan_pago['fecha'] = date('d/m/Y');
                                $plan_pago['valor'] = $data[$llave]['valor_aprobado'];
                                $plan_pago['id_periodo_presupuestario'] = 2;
                                $plan_pago['id_solicitud'] = $idSolicitud;
                                $plan_pago['id_concepto_pago'] = 'NULL';

                                $this->modelo->enviarPlanDePago($plan_pago);
                            }

                            try{
                                $pdf = $this- 
      >obtenerResolucionBase64("resolucion_".$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_resolucion'], 
     $pendientes_firma[$key]['fecha']);
                                $pdf = $this->obtenerFirmaWS($pdf, $value['folio'], 
     $user);
                                $this->guardarResolucion($pdf, 
      "resolucion_".$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_resolucion'], $pendientes_firma[$key] 
     ['fecha']);

                             
                                $firmar[$key]['id_resolucion'] =  
     $pendientes_firma[$key]['id_resolucion'];
                                if ($pendientes_firma[$key]['codi_externo_caso'] !== 
     '0') {
                                    $this->estadosSUF->actualizarProyectosSUF(
                                    $pendientes_firma[$key]['id_tipo_proyecto'], 
     $pendientes_firma[$key]['codi_externo_caso'],$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_voto'], 
     $user, $pendientes_firma[$key]['folio'], $pendientes_firma[$key]['fecha']);
                                    if ($es_subsidio) {
                                      $this- 
     >traspasarResolucionTransparencia($pendientes_firma[$key], $value['folio']);
                                     
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    /**
                                     * Emparejamiento de Estados de solicitud de credito 
      con los estados de comite
                                     * @var array
                                     */
                                    $estados = array(
                                        2 => 10, // aprobado votacion, provision
                                        3 => 9 // rechazado, rechazo en solicitud
                                    );
                                    // Si es de sistema unico se actualiza el estado de 
      la solicitud con el transaccional
                                    
      \Sicre2\Transaccional::actualizarEstadoSolicitud($valor['id_solicitud_credito'], 
      $estados[$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_voto']]);
                                }
                               
                                   $html = "";
```

//METODOS MENCIONADOS
en esta parte llamo al metodo dos veces, una para subir id_documento original y la otra para subir id_documento_transparencia, que deberia ejecutarse 4 veces

```
                        if(!$pendientes_firma[$key] 
   ['id_documento_original'] == null){
                        
                    
                         $subir =  $this->modelo- 
        >subirResolucion($pdf,$html,$pendientes_firma[$key] 
 ['id_documento_original'],0);
                        }
                         if(!$pendientes_firma[$key]['id_documento_transparencia'] == null) ){

                         
                             $respuesta =  $this->modelo- 
       >subirResolucion($pdf,$html,$pendientes_firma[$key] 
       ['id_documento_transparencia'],1);
                        }
                       
                       
                        
                         
                         
                            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                                $error .= $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: No entendí del todo el problema, ni dónde ocurre exactamente, pero, ¿no es mejor mandar un solo array con todo lo que haya que hacer en el método y luego trabajar con ese único array?

Comment: es que me llegan en dos arrays, tendria que unirlos o algo

Comment: No importa, puedes tomar los dos arrays y crear uno solo a partir de ellos y trabajar con ese sólo array. Y, si controlas el código que envía los dos arrays, haz que envíe uno solo, no dos. De todos modos, intenta plantear con más claridad el problema, leí la pregunta y no logro entender cuál es el problema, ni dónde.